# Discuss the following graphs(Differential Equations)

Tags: calculus, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

So I have a differential equations midterm coming up soon, and in my last exam I messed the graphing question up. It was very similar to the one I am posting. All the questions said was "Discuss the following graph(s)." However, I still have not been able to understand what am I supposed to "discuss?" Also, I've never really been good with graphs and I've been having a hard time in general with graphs of differential equations. Nevertheless, I also feel like "discuss" is very vague. Could anyone give me any advice and possibly the solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciated or reference to free online resources that might help me get a greater intuition of the graphs of Differential Equations.

EDIT: After emailing him and asking what he meant by "discuss" he said:

"Describe what you see using scientific language." However, I'm still confused.

Thank You,

Valentino Rodriguez

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first looks like a slope field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first graph seems to be slope field, slope field is simply the graph of the vectors which their length represents the slope at that specific point.
In addition, as you may have noticed, those vectors would be tangent to any curve being graphed.

Comment: Yes you are definitely correct, but I believe he is looking for more than that. I got less points for saying that and more. Sorry if I wasn't exactly precise in what he wanted, but that's part of the problem. The questions on his exams are very vague like this.

Comment: @Valentino I think you have not noticed what he wanted, or ask your classmate, it is impossible to ask a question without any intention, specially on an exam.Absolutely, if the question was vague, students would complain.

Comment: @Valentino Probably, he was looking for the statement, "In this graph, the curve should be always tangent to the slope field" or something like this.

Comment: Okay after emailing him asking what he meant he said "Describe what you see using scientific language." Do you have any suggestions as to what he may be referring to?